# how to get maximum out of multi dimentional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, math

```js
let a = [
  [1, 2, 3, [1, 233]],
  [33, 45, 65, 4, 111, 123],
  [34, 5, 6]
];

let max = a[0][1];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
    if (a[i][j] > max) {
      max = a[i][j];
      for (let k = 0; k < a[i][j].length; k++) {
        if (a[i][j][k] > max) {
          max = a[i][j][k];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(max);
```

Comment: `Math.max(...a.flat(Infinity))`

Answer (score 3):

You can flatten the array and use `Math.max()` to get the max.

```
> Math.max(...a.flat(Infinity))
233
```

Comment: `Infinity` will be bigger than any array depth - as the argument to flat is a limit, `Infinity` won't effect performance - it's not like the code will loop infinitely :p

Comment: @Bravo good point :)

Comment: Change your answer

Comment: @Bravo credits to you